# Consuming messages from remote ActiveMq queue

Tags: queue, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, apache-camel

How do I use Apache Camel's ActiveMQ component to connect to a remote instance of ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an endpoint for each of your ActiveMQ instances:

```
<bean id="instance1" 
   class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
   <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://server1:61616"/>
</bean>
...
<bean id="instance2" 
   class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
   <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://server2:61616"/>
</bean>
```

and then use it in routes as
`<from uri="instanceX:myQueue"/>` or `<to uri="instanceX:myQueue"/>`

Comment: **Thanks a lot Alex....** I have added this and I am trying to add the component as follows::

'CamelContext aContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
ActiveMQComponent comp = ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("vm://"The IP Address of remote system"?broker.persistent=false");
aContext.addComponent("jms",comp);'

With this I am not able to connect to the queue....

Comment: You need to specify url like tcp://host:port instead of vm:// for remote connection.

Comment: I did try ur above-mentioned suggestion but could not connect to the remote Queue... Am I missing something, I am afraid..... Can u plzz help ??? TIA

Comment: How is the remore ActiveMQ instance configured? Is the target port opened and not blocked on the activemq server? What errors do you see?

Comment: How do I check that the target port is opened or closed.. ???
Moreover, There are no errors shown at all.. [ Forgive me for being silly..I have just started using ActiveMQ ]

Comment: You could do it using telnet.